# How to specify the width/height of the shiny viewer window created by rstudio?

Tags: r, shiny, rstudio

When I call `shinyApp(ui=ui, server=server)` to launch a shiny app, rstudio creates a window with 960x1020 dimensions that I can't seem to change. I tried passing `options=list(width=1600)` but that doesn't seem to have any effect.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at runGadget with viewer dialogViewer

For a 1600 x 1200 pixel window:

```
vwr = dialogViewer('MyAppName', width = 1600, height = 1200)
runGadget(ui, server, viewer = vwr)
```

Comment: Dialog windows are contained within the RStudio window. Is there a way to change the size of the window created by `shinyApp` or a way to create a first-class window with `runGadget`?